# Vagrant share command missing

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant 1.8.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 hosting Debian Jessie.

I've set up an account with Atlas, logged in from the terminal, execute:

```
vagrant share
```

And I'm getting the help screen with the exit code `1`.

There seems to be an open issue at GitHub [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6896) from January '16. I've tried to troubleshoot myself with

```
vagrant up --debug 2>log
```

But nothing appears in the log when I do `share`.

A possibly weird thing is that the `share` command is missing among the commands at `/usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands`. It's also missing in the listing produced with:

```
vagrant list-commands
```

It's also missing [in the same folder at GitHub](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/99d29f17fa88b46e91bce85723ba0a305f4a05e2/plugins/commands) and I don't see it there in the GitHub history.

It's not missing in [the documentation](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/9c299a2a357fcf87f356bb9d56e18a037a53d138/website/source/docs/share/http.html.md) though.

I don't know Ruby, so there's not much point in reading `/usr/bin/vagrant`, which I did anyhow.

**UPDATE**

In reply to @jayhendren.

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-share
Installing the 'vagrant-share' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:946:in `all=': undefined method `group_by' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/bundler.rb:275:in `with_isolated_gem'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/bundler.rb:231:in `internal_install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/bundler.rb:102:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:62:in `block in install_plugin'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:72:in `install_plugin'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:37:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:14:in `action'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:32:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in `each'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in `execute'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:56:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:268:in `cli'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:173:in `<main>'
```

The same with `sudo`.

And I get the same error when I try to install any other plugin. I couldn't find `vagrant-share` listed anywhere as available anywhere. Unlike this one and called so:

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-netinfo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I found [a similar one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/K_CGRWsNAjc) and [one more](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5347), I kicked away the Ubuntu packaged `vagrant` and got an original one from [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html). Easy peasy, now it's ok.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `vagrant-share` plugin:

```
[birdsnest ~]% vagrant plugin install vagrant-share
Installing the 'vagrant-share' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Fetching: vagrant-share-1.1.6.gem (100%)
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-share (1.1.6)'!
[birdsnest ~]% vagrant list-commands
Below is a listing of all available Vagrant commands and a brief
description of what they do.

[...]

connect         connect to a remotely shared Vagrant environment

[...]

share           share your Vagrant environment with anyone in the world

[...]
```

Comment: `vagrant-share` should come by default. Strange!

Comment: @heemayl Vagrant Share appears to be an abandoned service (now called Atlas, and free hosting has been axed), so it's not surprising that most Vagrant packages no longer bundle `vagrant-share`.

Comment: Hmmm, came with my Ubuntu 14.04's recommended one though. +1